# Sonar - Remove this useless assignment to local variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swiftui, sonarqube

I have set the boolean value and stored as a user default. But `Sonar` gives me an error `Remove this useless assignment to local variable in SwiftUI`

What will be the way around for this?

I defined variable on the top
`@State private var showCartPage = false`

and onDisappear setting/comparing value like this

```
.onDisappear {
            @StoredPublished<UserDefaultsStorage>(key: StorageConfig.Userdefault.iscartPageShow) var setcartPageValue: Bool?

            setcartPageValue = self.showCartPage
Remove this useless assignment to local variable "setcartPageValue"
        }
```

Comment: Can you use the decorator directly on the `showCartPage` property and get rid of the whole `onDisappear` block? Otherwise change `setcartPageValue` from a local variable to an instance property.

Comment: @Paulw11 Actually I am setting this value on toggle, first `onAppear` I retrieve and then `onDisappear` i check the updated value if any.

Comment: But if you put the decorator on `showCartPage` doesn't the need to explicitly fetch and save just go away?  That's how you would use the `@AppStorage` decorator.

Comment: If I understand correctly that decorator is just a shortcut fro UserDefaults. Why not use UserDefaults directly: `UserDefaults.standard.set(elf.showCartPage, forKey: StorageConfig.Userdefault.iscartPageShow)`